# Windows to configure IIS Website to use a particular physical network interface

Tags: networking, iis, interface

How to configure on Windows 2003 server such that:-

1. when I access my website on the server, it uses IP address A.A.A.A
2. when my program runs it uses IP address B.B.B.B

Both A.A.A.A, B.B.B.B is configured on 2 different physical network interface on the server.

The reason for this is, my program is physically connected out from a particular network interface to reach another server. But I need the website to be using another network interface bacause that is where user will be accessing from.

```
Users <---> [Inf 1:Access website] MY SERVER [Inf 2:my prog to Svr A] <---> Server A
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the web site to the IP address of the appropriate NIC in the properties of the web site.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried this but when i launch the webpage its still pointing to B.B.B.B

Comment: Try stopping and restarting the web site. If that doesn't work then stop and restart IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply have 2 URLs for the site in DNS, one that points to A.A.A.A and another that points to B.B.B.B and then bind them appropriately in IIS.

Alternatively, you could also simply use http://localhost when accessing the site from the server itself and bind that to the proper IP.